# What usage/analytics information is available for iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, analytics

If you deploy an application through the iTunes app store, what usage information do you get from Apple?  Do you only get the number of downloads/sales, and does this differ for free vs. paid apps?  Do you get any information regarding how often it is used, crash logs, demographics info, etc?  Is the only way to build hooks to your own server to track this information and would such an app even get approved?

I've seen articles such as [this one](http://itmanagement.earthweb.com/entdev/article.php/3805481/iPhone-App-Usage-Trends-Revealed.htm) that includes quotes like:

> only about 20 percent of users return to use a free app the day after they first download it and by 30 days out, less than five percent are using the app.

Is that based on surveys, or is it data that comes from Apple?  There doesn't appear to be much publicly available data except when Apple shows the top applications, but that is just based downloads or ratings, and nothing deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only receive usage information if you somehow program the reporting of such information into your app.

Number of Downloads (Sales if a non-free app) and more recently crash logs are the only information you receive from Apple. you do not even receive personal information about WHO is was that bought your app, only that they did.

Answer (score 2):

Most of this information comes from companies like [Pinch Media](http://www.pinchmedia.com/) and [Admob](http://www.admob.com/). They supply libraries you can include in you app which inform their servers of events in your app (specifically launch but also other events decided by you).

They use these events to provide aggregate information on iPhone apps. Several reports have been published recently referencing this data.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get usage statistics from Apple, only download and sales statistics.  The reporting is slightly different for free apps(as they won't show up in the financial report), but basically the same information is provided.

You can however track usage information on your own by having your application ping a remote server every time the app is accessed.  You can use the unique device id to track a specific user.  This will be dependent on internet access for the iPhone/iPod Touch.

Apple does give you how many downloads have occurred as well as what countries they are from.  If you want more detailed usage statistics you will have to go to a third party solution, or write it yourself.

Unless Apple is secretly sending usage information when an app is opened, I don't see how anyone can get aggregate statistics about the whole app store.  When I upload an app, it is in binary format, and it is probably unlikely that anyone adds in their own code to secretly do this.